# Confirm a first and second choice selection in jQuery using radio buttons (or something better)?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, conditional-statements

The user needs to be able to select a first and second choice for time. I'm using radio buttons...however if there's something better I appreciate input.

I want an on page message saying "You have selected your first choice" when they select their first choice...and "You have selected your second choice" when they select their second.

Yes I realize this seems simple...I'm very new to jquery...

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<table class="tblWorkshop">
<tr>
<td>DAY ONE</td>
</tr>
<th>Morning Workshops</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>Afternoon Workshops</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<tr>
<td>9:00 am</td><td><input type="radio" name="choice"  class="firstChoice" value="0"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="choice"  class="secondChoice" value="1" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
<td>12:00 pm</td><td><input type="radio" name="choice"  class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="choice"  class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:30 am</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
<td>12:30 pm</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00 am</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
<td>1:00 pm</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:30 am</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
<td>2:30 pm</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:45 am</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
<td>3:45 pm</td><td><input type="radio" name="firstChoice" value="0" class="firstChoice"  />First Choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="SecondChoice" value="1" class="secondChoice" />Second Choice</td><td class="spotsLeft"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected =$('input[name=choice]:checked', '.tblWorkshop').val()

        if (selected == $('input[value=1]:checked', '.tblWorkshop').val()) {

            alert('First choice selected');

        }

        else if (selected == $('input[value=0]:checked', '.tblWorkshop').val()){
            alert('Second choice selected');
        }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use select boxes with multiple choices. There is even an example on the JQuery api page here: [val API page](http://api.jquery.com/val/)